# Getting average of all the values for a field in a Mongo DB collection using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Here's what the data looks like:

```
[{_id:1,price:"5"},{_id:2,price:"10"},{_id:3,price: null}]
```

The expected outcome is the average of all the values in the *price* field.i.e. average of 5 and 10, which is 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a group with an average (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      price: {
        $avg: "$price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

When executed this will output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "",
    "price": 7.5
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still not sure why I get price as null in the output

Comment: @HarshShringi are you replacing the `collection` with your own collection name?

Comment: I'm invoking the `aggregate()` on a mongoose model. After some fiddling, I figured that the field(price) is stored in the db as a string, and is a nullable field. The ask is to find out the avg of all the non-null fields stored as strings. Trying to figure that out... @kevin

Comment: @HarshShringi can you update your question with the actual data in your collection. thanks

Comment: Updated.  Here's what I tried: Filtering out the null values using $match(this worked). I'm currently trying to figure out how to convert the strings to numbers